# I'd like to format a record containing a number with a comma

Tags: php, sql, select

I'd like the format of a record containing a number to be displayed with a comma separating every 1,000. The value in the record is the total price of a product.

In a very simplistic format:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE model='A'";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo $row['totalprice'] ;
```

The 'totalprice' record in the table for this example model contains the amount 32830

So the current output is 32830.
The desired output I'd like is 32,830

I can't hard code the number in the code as there are many products to display with different costs.

Comment: number_format($row['totalprice'],0,"",",");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/number_format

`string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals , string $dec_point , string $thousands_sep )`

So, what you want is:

```
echo number_format($row['totalprice']);
```

Because:

> If only one parameter is given, number will be formatted without
>   decimals, but with a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

Comment: Ah perfect. Yes, I had tried this but was not using the () and was breaking the page. So obvious now. Many thanks.